# Dart double precision confusion

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a little confused about the precision of The Dart 'double' type,
for example,

```
void main() {
  double num1 = 0.55 * 10;  // 5.5
  double num2 = 0.55 * 100;  // 55.00000000000001
  double num3 = 0.55 * 1000; // 550
  double num4 = 0.45 * 100;  // 45
  print("num1: $num1, num2: $num2, num3: $num3, num4: $num4");
}
```

the print is:

```
num1: 5.5, num2: 55.00000000000001, num3: 550, num4: 45
```

just num2's precision is exceptional.

I don't know why. Can anyone help me with that? Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: Lol, tried it too and got the same result. You a genius, haha. Let it run like that

Comment: common problem in many languages. [read here](https://floating-point-gui.de/)